# Practical trigonometry question I can't figure out (Highschool Level)

Tags: trigonometry

"Jack is on a bearing of 260 degrees from Jill. What is Jill's bearing from Jack?"

The answer is 080 degrees. I really can't figure out how. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: From where is this question? I think there is some information missing. Also, can you show your ideas/approach?

Comment: It's from my textbook, nothing more. This is the exact question as it is worded. I don't have an approach because I don't know how the answer was derived.

Comment: Jill's bearing  should be the opposite direction of Jack's bearing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks more like a question in general relativity than trigonometry

If Jack is traveling on a bearing of $260^\circ$ relative to Jill then from Jacks perspective Jill is travelling in the exact opposite direction

Hence $260^\circ-180^\circ=080^\circ$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following diagram:
[image]

The rule about bearings is: "Point north and go clockwise".

The bearing of Jill from Jack $(\theta)$ and the angle $\gamma$ ($=260-180)$ are alternate angles, so they're equal.